# How to propagate a commit to child branches?

Tags: git, history

As you can see below, I have nested branches: step-1 is based on step-0, step-2 based on step-1 and so on.

I made a new commit on step-0 named "Updated instruction" (orange highlighted) and now I would like this commit to be applied on every child branches.
**=> Place "Updated instruction" commit between "Update step 0" and "step 1"**

**Actual**

[image: repo gitg visualisation]

**What I would like**

[image: What I would like]

I thought to checkout rebase push, one branch by one but I'm not sure it will works and it's a pain.

Comment: If you want to put a later commit on the parent branch at the origin of a child branches, you will need to rebase that child branch on the parent branch. I don't think there's an automated way to do that (especially since you're altering history and will need to force push if you want to push this upstream).

Comment: Yeh that's what I thought :(

Comment: why is merging so out of the question? I would just merge the three branches into one.

Comment: @Alex Merging won't put the `origin/step-0` commit before the other step branches. Plus, history will look really complicated.

Comment: as a side note - rebasing public (pushed) branches is *generally* a bad idea as every team member will have to rebase/reset them. See http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-6.html#The-Perils-of-Rebasing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `git checkout -b step-1 origin/step-1`:

```
git rebase origin/step-0
```

After that, `git checkout -b step-2 origin/step-2`:

```
git rebase step-1
```

Repeat until all branches have been linearized:

```
git checkout -b step-<n> origin/step-<n>
git rebase step-<n-1>
```

Lastly, `git checkout master`:

```
git rebase step-7
```

When you're done:

```
git push --force origin step-1 step-2 step-3 step-4 step-5 step-6 step-7 master
```

Of course that involves a lot of typing, but you can easily automate that in any scripting language. Arguably, you could save the time of writing a script for a one-off job and just get down doing your operations manually. :)

Comment: "It seems step-6and step-7 diverge in the current history, but your desired history doesn't show step-6." -> My mistake, forgot the step-6 branch tag when made the paint :p

Comment: OK, that's was my first idea, you confirmed it thank you. I hoped there was a lazy/smart way for doing it.

Comment: @Nicolas Writing a script is a smart solution. If it's faster than typing depends on your scripting skills. ;-)